# Can I still travel to Australia for a holiday on my Temporary Skills Shortage (subclass 482) visa if I will not be working for my sponsor?

Tags: australia, working-visas, change-purpose-of-travel

I have an Indian passport and a Temporary Skills Shortage (subclass 482) visa approved for myself and my wife to work in Australia for my sponsoring company. However, I would not be joining my sponsoring company in Australia as I have got another job offer in US.

Can I & my wife still travel to Australia on TSS 482 visa for a holiday/vacation and come back without having to start employment there?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  The [conditions attached to the subclass 482 visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/already-have-a-visa/check-visa-details-and-conditions/see-your-visa-conditions?product=482-64#) state that:

> holders **must** [...]
>   commence work within 90 days of arrival in Australia, if the visa was granted while the holder was outside Australia

This is probably *intended* to say that your visa will be cancelled if you don't start work within 3 months.  However, in your particular situation, it sounds like it's also OK for you to visit Australia without working for up to three months!

That said, I would not enjoy attempting to explain this to the immigration official on arrival, since if they find out you don't intend to work in the job you got the visa for, they will quite reasonably wonder if you're planning to work somewhere else illegally then.  But then again, given that you already have a firm US job offer (and visa, I hope?), it should be possible to convince them that you will not.

Long story short, **if you want to play it safe, it would be wise to get a regular Australian tourist visa**.  But if you're feeling lucky and want to try your current visa, you appear to have the law on your side.